# Best way to store list of websites on iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, plist

By best I mean most efficient.
So don't go on about subjectiveness.

I have a list of websites and I want to store the list on the iphone locally, there must be an URL, title and a small image (like 32x32 max image size). I don't think I should be using CoreData for this. Should I be using a plist?

EDIT:
Efficient's definition I though was obvious. Take up the least amount of room, use lowest memory/CPU. 
Sorry I forgot to say About 10-15 max items. And they just get loaded into a table view when the app first loads or when that view is brought back by a nav controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, leave the images in the resources, and put the url, title and imagename in a pList. Alternatively, you could just create a "Site" class with the three properties, and generate an array of Sites in code. (Or an Array of Dictionaries)

Comment: well the list has to be "staying", sorry i've forgotten the proper terminology. But it keeps the list between running the app.

Comment: If you are seeding the list initially, use a pList. Otherwise just store your array in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

You say not to "go on about subjectiveness" but you don't provide your definition of efficient for this.

You don't specify how many websites you want to store or how you want to use them or what is important to you - storage size, i/o perf, ability to query in specific ways etc.

It doesn't sound like a plist would be a bad fit but I guess my earlier point is just that way you are going to read, write data is generally equally or more important in setting context for questions like this.